# Unable to create a conda environment based on yaml file due dependencies issue (protobuf issue)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-3.6, miniconda

hope you're doing well.
Wanted to know if you could help me out with the following issue.

I am trying to recreate a conda environment (old) in my local macbook M2 with some issues.

Here is the `environment.yaml` for the mac.

```
name: airflow36
channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- blas=1.0=mkl
- intel-openmp=2019.1=144
- libgfortran=3.0.1=h93005f0_2
- mkl=2019.1=144
- numpy=1.15.4=py36hacdab7b_0
- numpy-base=1.15.4=py36h6575580_0
- python-daemon=2.1.2=py36_0
- airflow=1.10.1=py36_0
- alembic=0.8.10=py36_1
- appnope=0.1.0=py36_1000
- apscheduler=3.4.0=py36_0
- asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_1003
- attrs=18.2.0=py_0
- awscli=1.16.98=py36_0
- babel=2.6.0=py_1
- backcall=0.1.0=py_0
- bleach=2.1.2=py_0
- blinker=1.4=py_1
- boto=2.49.0=py_0
- boto3=1.9.88=py_0
- botocore=1.12.88=py_0
- ca-certificates=2020.6.24=0
- certifi=2020.6.20=py36_0
- cffi=1.11.5=py36h342bebf_1001
- chardet=3.0.4=py36_1003
- click=6.7=py_1
- colorama=0.3.9=py_1
- configparser=3.5.0=py36_1001
- cookies=2.2.1=py_0
- coverage=4.4.2=py36_0
- croniter=0.3.27=py_0
- cryptography=2.3.1=py36hdbc3d79_1000
- decorator=4.3.2=py_0
- defusedxml=0.5.0=py_1
- dicttoxml=1.7.4=py36_0
- dill=0.2.9=py36_0
- docutils=0.14=py36_1001
- entrypoints=0.3=py36_1000
- flake8=3.5.0=py36_0
- flask=0.12.4=py_0
- flask-admin=1.4.1=py36_0
- flask-appbuilder=1.11.1=py_1
- flask-babel=0.11.1=py_0
- flask-cache=0.13.1=py_1000
- flask-caching=1.3.3=py_0
- flask-login=0.2.11=py36_0
- flask-openid=1.2.5=py36_1003
- flask-sqlalchemy=2.1=py36_1
- flask-swagger=0.2.13=py36_0
- flask-wtf=0.14.2=py_1
- future=0.16.0=py36_1002
- gitdb2=2.0.5=py_0
- gitpython=2.1.11=py_0
- gunicorn=19.9.0=py36_1000
- html5lib=1.0.1=py_0
- icu=58.2=h0a44026_1000
- idna=2.8=py36_1000
- ipykernel=5.1.0=py36h24bf2e0_1002
- ipython=7.2.0=py36h24bf2e0_1000
- ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py_1
- iso8601=0.1.12=py_1
- itsdangerous=1.1.0=py_0
- jedi=0.13.2=py36_1000
- jinja2=2.8=py36_1
- jira=2.0.0=py_0
- jmespath=0.9.3=py_1
- jsonschema=3.0.0a3=py36_1000
- jupyter_client=5.2.4=py36_0
- jupyter_core=4.4.0=py_0
- libcxx=4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
- libcxxabi=4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
- libffi=3.2.1=h0a44026_1005
- libiconv=1.15=h1de35cc_1004
- libpq=9.6.3=0
- libsodium=1.0.16=h1de35cc_1001
- libxml2=2.9.8=hf14e9c8_1005
- libxslt=1.1.32=h33a18ac_1002
- llvm-meta=7.0.0=0
- lockfile=0.12.2=py_1
- lxml=3.8.0=py36_0
- mako=1.0.7=py_1
- markdown=2.6.11=py_0
- markupsafe=1.0=py36_0
- mccabe=0.6.1=py_1
- mistune=0.8.4=py36h1de35cc_1000
- mkl_fft=1.0.10=py36h470a237_1
- mkl_random=1.0.2=py36h1702cab_2
- mock=2.0.0=py36_0
- monotonic=1.5=py_0
- moto=1.1.1=py36_0
- mysql-connector-c=6.1.11=he2f1009_1
- mysqlclient=1.3.13=py36_1000
- nbconvert=5.4.1=py_2
- nbformat=4.4.0=py_1
- ncurses=5.9=10
- notebook=5.5.0=py36_0
- numexpr=2.6.4=py36_0
- oauthlib=2.1.0=py_0
- openssl=1.0.2u=h1de35cc_0
- pandas=0.24.0=py36h0a44026_0
- pandoc=2.6=0
- pandocfilters=1.4.2=py_1
- parso=0.3.3=py_0
- pbr=5.1.2=py_0
- pendulum=1.4.4=py36_0
- pep8=1.7.0=py36_0
- pexpect=4.6.0=py36_1000
- pickleshare=0.7.5=py36_1000
- pip=9.0.1=py36_1
- pluggy=0.6.0=py_0
- prompt_toolkit=2.0.8=py_0
- psutil=4.4.2=py36_0
- psycopg2=2.7.5=py36hdffb7b8_2
- ptyprocess=0.6.0=py36_1000
- py=1.7.0=py_0
- pyaml=18.11.0=py_0
- pyasn1=0.4.4=py_1
- pycodestyle=2.3.1=py_1
- pycparser=2.19=py_0
- pyflakes=1.6.0=py36_0
- pygments=2.3.1=py_0
- pyjwt=1.7.1=py_0
- pyopenssl=19.0.0=py36_0
- pyrsistent=0.14.9=py36h1de35cc_1000
- pysocks=1.6.8=py36_1002
- pytest=3.4.0=py36_0
- pytest-cov=2.5.1=py36_0
- pytest-mock=1.6.3=py36_1
- python=3.6.2=0
- python-dateutil=2.8.0=py_0
- python-editor=1.0.4=py_0
- python-nvd3=0.15.0=py_1
- python-slugify=1.2.6=py_0
- python3-openid=3.1.0=py36_1001
- pytz=2018.9=py_0
- pytzdata=2018.9=py_0
- pyyaml=3.12=py36_1
- pyzmq=17.1.2=py36h111632d_1001
- readline=6.2=0
- requests=2.21.0=py36_1000
- requests-oauthlib=1.0.0=py_1
- requests-toolbelt=0.9.1=py_0
- rsa=3.4.2=py_1
- s3transfer=0.1.13=py36_1001
- send2trash=1.5.0=py_0
- setproctitle=1.1.10=py36h1de35cc_1001
- setuptools=38.4.0=py36_0
- simple-salesforce=0.74.2=py36_0
- six=1.12.0=py36_1000
- smmap2=2.0.5=py_0
- sqlalchemy=1.1.18=py36h470a237_0
- sqlite=3.13.0=1
- tabulate=0.7.7=py36_0
- tenacity=4.8.0=py36_0
- terminado=0.8.1=py36_1001
- testpath=0.4.2=py36_1000
- thrift=0.11.0=py36h0a44026_1001
- tk=8.5.19=2
- tornado=5.1.1=py36h1de35cc_1000
- traitlets=4.3.2=py36_1000
- tzlocal=1.5.1=py_0
- unicodecsv=0.14.1=py_1
- unidecode=1.0.23=py_0
- urllib3=1.24.1=py36_1000
- wcwidth=0.1.7=py_1
- webencodings=0.5.1=py_1
- werkzeug=0.14.1=py_0
- wheel=0.30.0=py36_2
- wtforms=2.1=py36_0
- xmltodict=0.11.0=py_1
- xz=5.2.4=h1de35cc_1001
- yaml=0.1.7=h1de35cc_1001
- zeromq=4.2.5=h0a44026_1006
- zlib=1.2.11=0
- zope.deprecation=4.4.0=py_0
- pip:
  - apache-airflow==1.10.1
  - datadiff==1.1.6
  - funcsigs==1.0.0
  - ordereddict==1.1
  - pytest-pythonpath==0.7
  - python-logstash==0.4.5
  - google-api-core==1.14.2
  - google-api-python-client==1.7.11
  - oauth2client==4.1.2
  - cached-property==1.5.1
```

It seems it is causing a conflict when installing some dependencies because I got the following output when running `conda env create --force -f "$ENVIRONMENT_FILE"`

```
Pip subprocess error:
protobuf requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.6.2
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

It is weird because I'm not installing the `protobuf` library but it looks it is used in one of the libraries I am using.

Here is the conda info:

```
     active environment : airflow36
    active env location : /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/airflow36
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/username/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/username/.condarc
          conda version : 22.11.1
    conda-build version : 3.22.0
         python version : 3.9.13.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __osx=10.16=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /Users/username/opt/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/username/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/username/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/22.11.1 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.13 Darwin/21.6.0 OSX/10.16
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

# conda environments:
#
base                     /Users/username/opt/anaconda3
airflow36             *  /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/airflow36
                         /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base
```

Would someone faced the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: Error message says you need Python >= 3.7, but you specified: `python=3.6.2=0`

Comment: Correct, I'm trying to recreate that environment as it is, without any modification. It's supposed it worked at some point so wondering if libs can change their dependency.

Comment: well, this environment was built for intel chips, and those build probably don't exist for the M1 chips

Comment: To be clear, Apple released the first M1 chips in Nov 2020, python 3.6 was released Dec 2016

Comment: Thanks @PaulH. Do you think this issue is caused because I'm using M1 macbook? If I run this on a docker with ubuntu in the same machine would it work? (Going to test it as well today if possible)

Comment: This isn't necessarily an M1 problem *yet*, but even if you get everything installed as is, things like `mkl` simply will not work on non-Intel x86_64 hardware, emulation or no. You will absolutely have to modify the YAML to remove hardware specific constraints.

Comment: @PaulH the Python version isn't so much the problem here because OP is running the `osx-64` (not `osx-arm64`) version of Conda **base**, as indicated by the `conda info` platform value. Apple will try to seamlessly emulate `osx-64` versions of packages, and Conda will search the regular channels that do have the versions requested.

Comment: Thanks @merv. I guess the next step will be to use a Intel x86_64 hardward, correct?

Comment: First step I would take is to remove all of the version numbers to see if you can get *any* build. If that works add the version numbers back (perhaps <major>.<minor>) without the build numbers to see if you can get a solve. If that doesn't work, you could try pruning out low-level packages than aren't a direct concern.

Comment: You don't need to strip versions - just the builds (e.g., `=hf14e9c8_1005 `) and remove all `mkl` and `intel*` packages. There is a `--no-builds` argument that can expediate this (see `conda env export --help`).

Comment: thank you - as an update I have also tried to run this inside a docker ubuntu 18.04 image successfully (didn't throw any library exception) with the platform flag linux/amd64. Will try to remove the builds and see if that works as well on native mac m2.